# In TemplateHaskell, is there a way to get more accurate information about instances than what reifyInstance provides?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm currently writing a QuickCheck style library and relying on Template Haskell for generating a large number of test cases.

I want to generate code like:

```
quickCheck (prop_Num_plus_is_associative :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Property)
```

The property "prop_Monoid_plus_is_associative" has the following type:

```
prop_Num_plus_is_associative :: (Eq a, Monoid a, Show a) => a -> a -> a -> Property
```

so that I can check it with any appropriate instance of `Monoid`. However, sometimes, the types that my program chooses to fill in for "a" does not satisfy the context. I would like to filter out those cases by checking whether a certain instance exists.

However, when I call `reifyInstance` on `Monoid (Max Integer)`, it only gives me the list of instances that it could possibly match, namely `(Bounded a, Ord a) => Monoid (Max a)`, it does not do the rest of the work of checking whether `Integer` is `Bounded` and `Ord`. Is there a function similar to `reifyInstance` that does?

Edit:

Here the program that I was hinting at:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}

import Data.Semigroup

import Language.Haskell.TH

main :: IO ()
main = do
    $(do
        tMaxInt <- [t| Max Integer |]
        runIO . putStrLn . pprint =<< reifyInstances ''Monoid [ tMaxInt ]
        [e| return () |] )
```

It outputs

```
instance (GHC.Classes.Ord a_0,
          GHC.Enum.Bounded a_0) => GHC.Base.Monoid (Data.Semigroup.Max a_0)
```

despite the fact that `Max Integer` is not a `Monoid`.

Comment: Could you post an example program? I couldn't reproduce. (in fact, I couldn't make `reifyInstances` working at all)

Comment: TH is not going to do constraint unification. You should not try to check complex constraints like this yourself - just insert constraints for a fixed set of types which you know are monoids (or allow the user to specify which monoids to use, indicating they must submit valid `Monoid`s).